# Using SHOW COLUMNS with LIKE clause in PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-like

I have no idea why this isn't working:

```
    $stmt_field_exists = $db->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS
        FROM uf_users
        LIKE :field_name");

    $sqlVars[':field_name'] = "%display_name%";
```

I get an error on the `prepare` statement, 
`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 3`

At first I thought I was either using the `SHOW COLUMNS` query incorrectly, or forming the placeholder incorrectly, but when I try either of those two in isolation, they work fine:

```
    // Works fine
    $stmt_field_exists = $db->prepare("SELECT display_name
        FROM uf_users
        WHERE display_name LIKE :value");

    $sqlVars[':value'] = "%admin%";


    // Also works fine
    $stmt_field_exists = $db->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS
        FROM uf_users
        LIKE '%display_name%'");
```

I'm using MySQL 5.5.31.  What the heck is going on here?  Did I find a bug?

Comment: Please, provide full error message.

Comment: Could you create a minimal code to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Dang, should have asked this question during peak hours.  This should be working as is, provided you've defined `$db` as a PDO database object (which I do, of course).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full function is as follows:

```
function fetchUserField($user_id, $field_name){    
try {
    global $db_table_prefix;

    $db = pdoConnect();

    $sqlVars = array();

    // First, check that the specified field exists.  Very important as we are using other unsanitized data in the following query.
    $stmt_field_exists = $db->prepare("SHOW COLUMNS
        FROM ".$db_table_prefix."users
        LIKE :field_name");

    $sqlVars[':field_name'] = "%" . $field_name . "%";

    $stmt_field_exists->execute($sqlVars);

    if (!($results = $stmt_field_exists->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
        // The field does not exist
        return false;
    }

    $query = "SELECT 
        `$field_name`
        FROM ".$db_table_prefix."users
        WHERE
        id = :user_id
        LIMIT 1";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

    $sqlVars[':user_id'] = $user_id;

    $stmt->execute($sqlVars);

    if (!($results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))){
        // The user does not exist
        return false;
    }

    $stmt = null;
    return $results[$field_name];

} catch (PDOException $e) {
  addAlert("danger", "Oops, looks like our database encountered an error.");
  error_log("Error in " . $e->getFile() . " on line " . $e->getLine() . ": " . $e->getMessage());
  return false;
} catch (ErrorException $e) {
  addAlert("danger", "Oops, looks like our server might have goofed.  If you're an admin, please check the PHP error logs.");
  return false;
}
```

}

Simply using it like so

```
// Return the timestamp when this user's account was registered 
$author = fetchUserField($user_id, $field);
```

This fails to pull data though simply keeps returning false for some reason.